# How can I extract a URL from url("http://www.example.com")?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the URL of an element's background image with jQuery:

```
var foo = $('#id').css('background-image');
```

This results in something like `url("http://www.example.com/image.gif")`.  How can I get just the "http://www.example.com/image.gif" part from that?  `typeof foo` says it's a string, but the `url()` part makes me think that JavaScript and/or jQuery has a special URL type and that I should be able to get the location with `foo.toString()`.  That doesn't work though.

Comment: It's not Javascript but CSS see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#uri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that different browser implementations may return the string in a different format.  For instance, one browser may return double-quotes while another browser may return the value without quotes.  This makes it awkward to parse, especially when you consider that quotes are valid as URL characters.

I would say the best approach is a good old check and `slice()`:

```
var imageUrlString = $('#id').css('background-image'),
    quote = imageUrlString.charAt(4),
    result;

if (quote == "'" || quote == '"')
    result = imageUrlString.slice(5, -2);
else
    result = imageUrlString.slice(4, -1);
```

Assuming the browser returns a valid string, this wouldn't fail.  Even if an empty string were returned (ie, there is no background image), the result is an empty string.

Comment: I didn't know quotes were valid in URLs.  Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider regular expressions in this case:

```
var urlStr = 'url("http://www.foo.com/")';
var url = urlStr.replace(/^url\(['"]?([^'"]*)['"]?\);?$/, '$1');
```

This particular regex allows you to use formats like `url(http://foo.bar/)` or `url("http://foo.bar/")`, with single quotes instead of double quotes, or possibly with a semicolon at the end.

Comment: Although it's unlikely, this could fail where quotation characters formed part of the URL.  They aren't encoded by default so, for instance, if an image hosting service decided to start using quotes in their hashes you might see a url like `http://imgsvc.com/aSK'dslcpe"`.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, I was assuming encoded URLs.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string at each `"` and get the second element:

```
var foo = $('#id').css('background-image').split('"')[1];
```

Note: This doesn't work if your URL contains quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special URL type - it's a string representing a CSS url value. You can get the URL back out with a regex:

```
var foo = ${'#id').css('background-image');
var url = foo.match(/url\(['"](.*)['"]\)/)[1];
```

(that regex isn't foolproof, but it should work against whatever jQuery returns)

Comment: `match()` would return an array - you'd probably just want to specify to grab the first member of it.

Comment: you're right, though it would be the second element (the matching group)

Answer (score 1):

If it's always the same, I'd just take the substring of the URL without the prefix.

For instance, if it's always:

```
url("<URL>")
url("<otherURL>")
```

It's always the 5th index of the string to the len - 2

Not the best by all means, but probably faster than a Regex if you're not worried about other string formats.